# XML won't load class TestNG Java

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng

Getting below error when trying to run my xml. Looks like its having trouble loading the class but I have the correct class path.

> org.testng.TestNGException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:340)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:109)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:307)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.forName(ClassHelper.java:96)

The class path for the class I want to run is `src/test/java/com/homepage/company/AboutUsTest.java`
and my `xml` looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name = "AboutUs-Test" verbose = "1" parallel = "false">

<test name = "AboutUs" preserve-order="true">
<groups></groups>

<classes>
<class> name = "com.homepage.company.AboutUsTest"</class>
</classes>

</test>
</suite>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be so :

```
<class name = "com.homepage.company.AboutUsTest"/>
```

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks!